# Open Api 3.0 HEAD with no responses property

Tags: swagger, openapi

Is it possible to **not** include responses object with open api 3.0.1?

```
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
 version: '1.0'
 title: Hello World API
paths:
 /hello-health:
  head:
     description: Head hello world
  security: []
  operationId: helloworld-read
```

I am getting error Errors
Hide

Structural error at paths./hello-health.head
should have required property 'responses'
missingProperty: responses

I tried different variation, including empty property responses, empty object and it always fails the validation.

Example can be preview on https://editor.swagger.io/

Answer (score 3):

The `responses` element is optional starting from OpenAPI 3.1 (`openapi: 3.1.0`).

In OpenAPI 2.0 and 3.0, the `responses` element [is required](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.3.md#user-content-operationresponses) and [must contain at least one](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.3.md#responsesObject) response definition. You can use the `default` response instead of specific HTTP status codes.

```yaml
paths:
 /hello-health:
   head:
     responses:
       default:   # <-----
         description: Description of the default response
```